# how to check if value exists in realtime database firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a realtime database on firebase and having no issues adding and removing data in tables etc.
I currently have it setup like this:

[image]

So my goal is to check if a given value is inside my database currently.
for example, I would like to check if 'max' is currently a username in my database.

```
      var data = db.ref('loginInfo/');

      data.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        _this.users = snapshot.val()
      });
```

That is how I get all the values, it is saved into _this.users

(How do i check if a value is inside this object, i am making a login program)

if i console.log the object, this is what I see:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWAJS.png)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, but I think you might be helped by following the examples in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to save user passwords without hashing them. Just for practice reasons it is ok, but when users are going to enter real passwords you don't want to save them this way. See [How (not) to store passwords](https://itnext.io/how-not-to-store-passwords-4955569e6e84)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a child node exists under `loginInfo` where the `username` property has a value of `max`, you can use the following query for that:

```
var ref = db.ref('loginInfo/');
var query = ref.orderByChild('username').equalTo('max');

query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.exists());
});
```

I'd also recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), as there are many more options.